# Como remover as linhas com base nos valores de outra variável?

Tags: r, dataframe

Considere o dataframe:

```
data<-data.frame(a=c(1,3,4,5,6,NA,6,NA),b=c(1,NA,NA,4,6,7,NA,1))
```

Quero eliminar toda a linha quando existe `NA` **na variável 'a'**. Assim, o que espero é:

```
data
  a  b
1 1  1
2 3 NA
3 4 NA
4 5  4
5 6  6
6 6 NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `filter` do pacote `dplyr` atende o que você deseja

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  filter(!is.na(a))

  a  b
1 1  1
2 3 NA
3 4 NA
4 5  4
5 6  6
6 6 NA
```

Nesse caso eu filtrei os elementos que não são `NA` (`!is.na`) da variável `a`